# redshift sql using regular expression to get first, second, third values from a string which is like following

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

pattern: `d0=123;d1=134;d2=123;d3=13;d4=33;d5=44;d6=55;`

If want to get the first number between `=` `&` `;`

```
output: 
123
```

If I want to get the second occurrence between `=` `&` `;`

```
output: 
134
```

regex used:

```
select  
  regexp_substr(' d0=123;d1=134;d2=123;d3=13;d4=33;d5=44;d6=55;','d[0-9]+=' ,1,2) as b;
```

but output is coming like this:

```
d1=
```

Any pointers in this direction will be helpful.

Comment: It does not look like the Amazon Redshift `regex_substr` supports capturing group extraction. Try `regexp_replace(s, '.*;d1=([^;]+).*', '\1')` to extract the `d1` value.

Comment: select  
  regexp_substr('d0=123;d1=134;d2=123;d3=13;d4=33;d5=44;d6=55;', '(d[0-9]+=[0-9]+;)',1,7) as b;

This gives output as::
d6=55;

Iam still trying to avoid d6&; from above output

Comment: could you replace all = with a ;, then use split_part(yourstring,';',2) and then use 4 for the next value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to use regex_substr instead

```
regex_substr(s,'[^d=;]*[0-9]+[^;=d]',1,2)
```

Increment/decrement the integer value 2 as needed.

Comment: This won't match one-digit numbers, like `d0=3;`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is known limitation, but since non capturing blocks are not supported in redshift regex ..there is no choice left